# Why do curly braces and/or whitespace make a difference?

Tags: javascript, chaining, arrow-functions

Why is this-

```
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  const sqr = arr.filter((numbers) => {
    numbers > 0 && Number.isInteger(numbers)
  }).map((numbers) => {
    Math.pow(numbers, 2)
    })
  return sqr;
};
```

functionally different to this-

```
const squareddList = (arr) => { 
  "use strict";
  const sqr = arr.filter((numbers) => numbers > 0 && Number.isInteger(numbers)).map((numbers) => Math.pow(numbers, 2))
  return sqr; 
}
```

when the only difference between them is whitespace and curly braces?

When you pass an arbitrary array to both functions, the first returns an empty array and the second returns an array which has been filtered to only include positive integers and then squared.

Comment: The inner lambda passed to `arr.filter` in the curly braces example doesn't have a `return` statement, so the function doesn't return anything and the filter returns an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

Arrow functions without curly braces implicitly return the result of the expression in the function body so:

```
const someFunction = () => 10
someFunction(); // Returns 10
```

is equivalent to

```
const someFunction = () => {
  return 10;
}
someFunction(); // Returns 10
```

and is **NOT** equivalent to:

```
const someFunction = () => {
  10;
}
someFunction(); // Returns undefined
```

Comment: Yup. Other languages such as C# work in a similar fashion, but you'd get a design time error as there's no syntax support for implicit "return" statement.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is because in the first one you don't `return` the values. 
In arrow function, if you put curly brackets you need to return the value, if not the values are returned.

```
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  const sqr = arr.filter((numbers) => {
    return numbers > 0 && Number.isInteger(numbers)
  }).map((numbers) => {
    return Math.pow(numbers, 2)
  })
  return sqr;
};
```

This will work.